# Mapa concesional

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué es un [mapa concesional](https://cincodias.elpais.com/economia/2023-06-21/madrid-extendera-el-descuento-del-abono-de-transporte-hasta-fin-de-ano.html)? Parece que tiene algo que ver con participar en una subasta pública ofreciendo la ejecución de un servicio a cambio de la obtención de dinero u otros beneficios, pero no estoy seguro. ¡Muchas gracias!

"Además, Díaz Ayuso ha subrayado durante el debate que unificará las tarifas del transporte público en dos únicas zonas -Madrid capital (A) y el resto de la región (B)-; esta medida en favor de los usuarios se podrá poner en marcha cuando entre en funcionamiento el nuevo mapa concesional, pues por primera vez será licitado de manera íntegra todo el sistema de concesiones de la red interurbana y urbana de transporte en autobús de la región."

Answer (score 1):

Según el DLE

[concesión](https://dle.rae.es/concesi%C3%B3n#A7vOPVe)

3. f. Der. Negocio jurídico por el cual la Administración cede a una persona facultades de uso privativo de una pertenencia del dominio público o la **gestión de un servicio público** en plazo determinado bajo ciertas condiciones.

En tu contexto, la red de transportes públicos (autobuses, tranvias, metro, ...) de la Comunidad de Madrid es el servicio público cuya gestión se cede a las empresas.

**Mapa concesional** es un mapa de las concesiones, en este caso de aquellas relacionadas con el transporte público en la Comunidad de Madrid. El mapa reflejará los distintos servicios de transporte y a qué empresa se le ha otorgado la concesión en dicha comunidad. Completar el mapa quiere decir que todos los servicios pendientes de concesión tienen asociada una empresa que los gestionará en los próximos años.

Para que se le asigne una concesión a una empresa, ésta tiene que participar en un proceso de licitación o subasta pública, como indicas.